# How do I drag (and drag without holding) and drop with the force touch trackpad?

Tags: macos, keyboard, finder, trackpad, settings

I just upgraded from a 2013 MBP to a 2018 MBP, which has the force touch trackpad.

I used to be able to "Drag and Drop" by simply double tapping (*not clicking down*) an item and then dragging it to a new location. Additionally, I did not have to hold down my finger continuously on the trackpad to do so. I am neither able to achieve the simple drag nor the drag without holding methods on the new force touch trackpad.

**How do I drag and drop on the new force touch trackpad? 
How do I do so without holding my finger down continuously?**

I can't find anything useful under the trackpad settings.

Answer (score 2):

For macOS Monterey (and earlier?), you can configure this under *System Preferences* > *Accessibility* > *Pointer Control* and clicking the *Trackpad Options* button. In the dialog window, select *Enable dragging*.

[image]